# Loud Pop from DL380G5--then neither PSU lights up when plugged in

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, electrical-power, power-supply-unit

I wanted to fire up my old DL380 G5 server recently, and maybe one second after I hit the power button and the fans started to rev up, I heard a loud pop and suddenly it shut down.  Now neither PSU lights the LED near the power cable.  The machine was not excessively loaded with graphics cards, many HDDs (only had one), etc.

Unfortunately, I saw a few strands of uncured carbon fiber floating around near the server, and maybe one was sucked into contact with a circuit or something(??).  I didn't see any evidence of this near the hard drive bay, which seemed to be where the pop came from (hard to tell).

The outlets work for other machines, so the building's circuit breaker was not tripped.

Has anyone had this sort of thing before?  If I buy replacement power supplies, what is the probability that the server will work?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The usual source for "pop" sound is a failed capacitor, and most often these are in the PSUs.

Comment: Where are you in the world?

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I'm in the US.  I should be able to just buy one PSU and run the server off that, without backup, if it is in fact not damaged in other ways, right?

Comment: @C.M. How could _we_ tell you? You'll have to see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Who knows?

It's 10+ year-old equipment. It likely needs repair.
You can try replacement parts because they'll be inexpensive at this point, but you may have to replace several components.